# Keystore not working to change win to mac?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, keystore, android-keystore

[image]

I was created keystoree on window 8 and now i have use it on my macbook but it not working. so please help me .

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar situation. Maybe I got lucky, but I just kept trying to sign the app and from the second or third try it actually successfully signed it with no errors.